# Create variable size columns from tab deleminated file

Tags: terminal, bash, formatting

I would like to columnize data from excel.  I need to paste the data in a simple text file. Tabs need to be replaced with blanks. What I need is to be able to select the column width.How

[image]

```
cat mdhousenames.txt  | column -c7  -s \t  -x
```

How do I make this output nicely formatted with tabs expanded?

[image]
If possible, I'd like to go with native macOS 10.10.5 software. bash terminal is fine.

I've seen:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31239/how-to-expand-tabs-based-on-content
but no w3m command.  Where is a safe place to download, if this is the only way.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57222/how-can-i-use-column-to-delimit-on-tabs-and-not-spaces
but the tabs are a fixed size.  Can I make the tabs variable size?

---

answer:

```
 expand -t 16,29,34,50,57,72  mdhousenames.txt
```

Note: the first column starts in the unmentioned column 1. So in this example, the second column starts in column 16.

Comment: Tabs are always a variable size. What they are expanded to depends on the viewer app. How are you using this file?

Comment: cat mdhousenames.txt  | column -c7  -s \t  -x  How would I modify this to work?

Comment: I'm pasting it into TextWrangler/BBedit.

Comment: You said, "Tabs need to be replaced with blanks."... well what the heck are "blanks"!?

Comment: @user3439894- From the korn shell manual:` A blank is a tab or a space.` and from the bash manual:` blank  A space or tab.`

Comment: @fd0 Nothing like a circular situation! ;-)